# Saving individual sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently we have a Excel VBA application, which consists of 25-30 Excel sheet (and all of those sheets all hidden and we do background processing on them and display it to VBA forms UI), and we have developed a UI using VB forms. But problem we are facing is whenever we click on Save button using this code:

`ThisWorkbook.Save`

But this saves entire workbook not an individual sheet, so even if we make changes in single sheet it saves entire workbook and this save processing makes very slow (since it needs to save all excel sheet containing lot of data unnecessary, even if there is no changes).

My question is is there any way we can save "only one sheet in a particular excel sheet" not an entire excel file?

**Note:** I am a Java developer and I worked on VBA before, But it was years back, and I have forgotten bit. Any guidance would be appreciated. Or any pointers on how to handle this situation would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information, I can edit this question.

**What I have tried already?** I did a lot of research from yesterday, I searched in previous questions on SO, but didn't get any useful information. As per my research it says we cannot do this. Am I on right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider splitting your application into multiple workbooks:

1. The workbook that contains all the logic, user forms and programming code. This workbook handles all other workbooks as well as the displaying of it. Potentially, this could be even an "Application Specific Addin", that stays dormant but activates as soon as any of it's subsequent workbooks gets opened. For this architecture approach check out the section on "Application Specific Addins" in [this link](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=31159&BookID=22107&PageIndex=21&Language=3).
   This workobook/add-in can also hide the other workbooks, so that the user will not notice it's multiple workbooks.
2. One or multiple data workbooks: Depending how interlinked the data is, you can separate this, e.g. in a "Sales data" workbook which contains the large database, as "Base data" workbook, that contains all the smaller data (e.g. products or stores tables).

This way, you can reduce the saving to the "relevant" sheets. However, of course this requires quite a bit of reprogramming - but it's worth the effort, as for instance it also allows to provide updates/bug fixes without having the transfer the data between versions, as you only need to distribute the the file with programming logic. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. You cannot save a single worksheet at a time.

You may want to try to reduce the amount of data in the workbook. Try storing data in several workbooks and when it is needed, open that specific workbook, make the needed changes, and then close it.

If it is necessary to have access to all data at once then consider using access or some other database.

It is also possible that the sheets have "blank data". Cells that don't contain anything in them but excel thinks they do so when saving it tries to save way more than needed.

Comment: I have around between 1000-2000 rows in excel sheet, and is it possible to open workbook in background ie without user seeing that multiple workbooks are opened?

Comment: Can you store the data in the worksheets in different workbooks and then at run time open the workbooks with data you need, make the changes, and then close them? Unfortunately I don't know if there is another solution to your problem other than to save only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: I am ok with multiple workbooks, but user shouldn't see them, as we have hidden all sheets and manipulating only with VBA from

Comment: If you do Application.ScreenUpdating = False and Application.DisplayAlerts = False before you open the workbook and change both back to true after the book is closed the user will not see the changes made.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that it is the active worksheet that you want to save then you could do something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close True, "path"
```

This copies the active worksheet which creates a new workbook which will become the active workbook. Then just call the close method on that and give it a file name.